# "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" error on creating a Dynamic web project

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

For a standalone project with the same MYSQL Connector, I am able to connect to database, I am not getting any error. This error is coming only for Dynamic Web project though I have added the"mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin"jar file Can someone help??

Answer (score 0):

The mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar must be inside of WEB-INF/lib folder

Answer (score 0):

add the mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar to the build path, if that does not resolve add under the projects lib folder